# Unterschied zwischen "begrenzt" und "beschränkt"

Tags: difference, word-choice, synonym

Gibt es einen Unterschied im Gebrauch dieser Partizipien? Zum Beispiel, welche aus diesen Alternativen wäre korrekt?

> Die Zeit, die wir in Anspruch nehmen können, ist begrenzt.
>   Die Zeit, die wir in Anspruch nehmen können, ist beschränkt.

Comment: Verwandt: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6681/2594

Comment: Einen weiteren Unterschied gibt es, der in den bisherigen Antworten nicht erwähnt wurde, aber keine eigene Antwort wert ist: »Beschränkt« kann auch eine Person sein. Damit ist in einem abwertenden Sinn gemeint, dass sie nur über geringe intellektuelle Fähigkeiten verfügt. Das Wort ist in diesem Zusammenhang also auch ein Synonym von »dumm«. Das trifft auf »begrenzt« nicht zu. Eine Person kann nicht *begrenz* sein; das ergäbe keinen Sinn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beide deiner angegebenen Sätze sind korrekt.
Unterschiede gibt es zwischen den Adjektiven dennoch.
So kann „begrenzt“ auch für räumliche Begrenzungen genutzt werden.

> Der Zaun begrenzt den Garten.

Dieser Satz ist korrekt.

> Der Zaun beschränkt den Garten.

ist inhaltlich nicht so schön; lässt die Assoziation zu, dass der Zaun den Garten bei einer Tätigkeit hindert.

Answer (score 8):

Verben sind es nicht, sondern Adjektive. Beide Versionen erscheinen mir möglich, aber die erste ist besser. *Beschränkt* ist eher ein Wort der Fachsprache, z. B. in der Mathematik. Dennoch ist der zweite Satz verständlich.
Zusatzbemerkung: Im Jargon der Mathematik gibt es noch gewisse, von *beschränkt* abgeleitete Begriffe. Z. B. lernt jeder Student die Bedeutung der folgenden Aussage kennen: Ein metrischer Raum ist genau dann kompakt, wenn er vollständig und totalbeschränkt ist.

Comment: Oder genau Partizipien :)

Answer (score 5):

Ich bin entschieden für die Variante:

> Die Zeit, die wir in Anspruch nehmen können, ist begrenzt

### Erklärung

Diese Wörter haben ähnliche Bedeutungen und meist fällt es mir nicht auf wenn sie vertauscht werden.

Bei "beschränkt" liegt meines Erachtens jedoch häufiger eine äußere **Einschränkung** vor. Betrachten wir etwa folgenden Satz, in dem ich nicht "begrenzt" verwenden würde:

> «Aber das phantastisch veranlagte Kind hatte dieses unnütze Gemach, das von den verschmutzten Fenstern unbeschränkten Blick in die Ferne gab, gerade wegen seiner geheimnisvoll nutzlosen Art sich als eigenste Spielwelt und Versteck gewählt;»
> *Zweig, Stefan*. **«Ungeduld des Herzens»**

Auch im folgenden passt nach meinem Empfinden "beschränkt" besser, da man das niedrige Gehalt als leidiges äußeres Hemmnis empfindet.

> mit solchen beschränkten Mitteln kann man sich doch keine Existenz aufbauen.
> *Zweig, Stefan*. **«Ungeduld des Herzens»**

Hier ist ein Beispiel wo ich beide Wörter als zulässig ansehe und "beschränkt" vielleicht sogar vorziehe:

> «innerhalb unserer begrenzten, bornierten Froschperspektive!»
> Zweig, Stefan*. **«Ungeduld des Herzens»**

Entweder verdeutlicht dies die begrenzte Gültigkeit meiner Theorie, oder aber der Autor wollte verhindern, dass  "beschränkt" als "dümmlich" verstanden wird.

Ein ausgezeichnetes Beispiel eines Satzes in welchem nur "begrenzt" stehen darf ist folgender:

> Seit ich meine Aufgabe begrenzt wußte, fühlte ich eine Art neuer Kraft.
> Zweig, Stefan*. **«Ungeduld des Herzens»**

Hier ist nicht von einer Einschränkung die Rede, sondern von einer wohldefinierten, klar abgesteckten Aufgabe.

Zu meiner Theorie passt, dass "begrenzt" sich von "Grenze" herleitet - und Grenzen sind oft immaterieller Natur - während "beschränkt" von "Schranke" kommt und "Schranken" sind meist massive Hindernisse. Ich würde in der Regel dieser Variante den Vorzug geben:

> Die Zeit, die wir in Anspruch nehmen können, ist begrenzt.

Aber eher sagen:

> Der Chef beschränkte die zulässige Laufzeit auf 2 Monate.

Dennoch würde mir eine Vertauschung der Begriffe kaum auffallen.

Für Zäune und andere Grenzen würde ich intuitiv **begrenzen** vorziehen, es sei den sie beschränken jemanden in einer Handlung.

Wenn "begrenzt" für "gering" steht würde ich nicht "beschränkt" verwenden:

> An Briefmarken hatte er nur ein sehr begrenztes Intresse.

In folgenden Redewendungen sehe ich stets "beschränkt".

> Er ist beschränkt = dumm

> wir beschränken uns auf das Thema...

Bei letzterer Formulierung bedingte wohl die Eitelkeit der Autoren die Wahl. So mancher Autor möchte uns glauben machen er hätte wohl die Fähigkeiten, die dazu nötig wären noch viele andere Gebiete der Astrophysik minutiös zu behandeln - aber, ach - die lästigen Verpflichtungen zwängen ihn, sich selbst zu hemmen... Keineswegs möchte er in der Regel sagen, er verzichte wegen begrenzten Wissens auf eine relativistische Behandlung!

Answer (score 5):

Begrenzt weist darauf hin, dass etwas aufhört.

> Die Grenze des Gartens begrenzt das Grundstück.

Beschränkt meint, dass etwas daran gehindert wird, sich weiter auszubreiten oder fortzusetzen.

> Obwohl wir großen Hunger hatten, beschränkten wir uns auf eine kleine Mahlzeit.

Answer (score 2):

"Begrenzt" legt die Betonung auf die eigentliche Grenze.

"Unsere Zeit is begrenzt, weil wir den Tagungsraum nur für zwei Stunden gemietet haben" - das Ende der Mietzeit ist die Grenze.

"Unsere Zeit ist beschränkt, weil wir noch zwei andere Themen bearbeiten müssen" - es gibt keine direkte Grenze, aber wir haben nicht beliebig viel Zeit.

Answer (score 1):

Eine Grenze ist erweiterbar. Deshalb kann ein in seinem Wissen und Geist begrenzter Mensch durchaus wissender und differenzierter werden.
Eine Schranke ist offen oder zu. Deshalb ist bei einem beschränkten Menschen die Schranke zu. Aus Ignoranz oder Unvermögen.

Answer (score 0):

"Begrenzt" ist drinnen einer Grenze. "Beschränkt" ist drinnen ein Bereich oder eine Menge.

Sie sind ähnlich, aber nicht das Selbe.

"Begrenzt" is within a boundary. "Beschränkt" is within a scope, or an amount.

They are similar but not the same.

Comment: In Satz 2 fügst Du mit "ein Bereich oder eine Menge" etwas zu, ohne im Beispiel 1 etwas äquivalentes anzubieten, präsentierst es aber als Unterscheidungsmerkmal. Was wird denn begrenzt - kein Bereich und keine Menge? Kann eine Schranke eine Grenze markieren?

Answer (score 0):

Die Worte [Grenze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenze) und [Schranke](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schranke) beschreiben ja beide ein Konstrukt das einen davon abhalten soll oder davon abhält einen Bereich zu betreten. Insofern sind auch die assozierten Begriffe davon in dem Sinne recht ähnlich und häufig synonym.

Allerdings hat eine Grenze eher etwas entgültiges und eine Schranke begrenzt nur temporär oder unter bestimmten Umständen.

> Die Zeit, die wir in Anspruch nehmen können, ist begrenzt.

Also hier ist einfach nicht mehr Zeit verfügbar.

> Die Zeit, die wir in Anspruch nehmen können, ist beschränkt.

Während das so klingt also hätte jemand die Zeit bewusst so festgelegt wäre aber womöglich noch flexibel. Funktionieren würde vermutlich beides, aber das erste würde sich besser anhören, weil "(unsere) Zeit ist begrenzt (endlich)" als idiom für sich genommen stehen kann. Bei "die Zeit ist beschränkt..." würde man eher ein "die Zeit ist auf [konkreter Wert] beschränkt" erwarten.

Answer (score 0):

Eine Grenze ist gegeben, eine Schranke wird gesetzt.  Die Handyspielzeit eines Kindes wird durch die Akkukapazität begrenzt und durch die Eltern beschränkt.  Der Begriff "beschränkt" impliziert eine verantwortliche Instanz, der Begriff "begrenzt" eher eine Ursache oder ein natürliches Ende.

Die Abgrenzung im normalen Sprachgebrauch ist aber eher verwaschen.

Answer (score -5):

grenze = final

schranke = hinderung dann durchlass

begrenzt heißt dass ein finales ziel schon erkannt wurde wonach nichts mehr kommt

beschränkt heißt dass es aufgrund irgendwelcher umstände nicht möglich ist zu garantieren dass der durchlass erfolgt

begrenzt ist eine klippe, beschränkt ist ein engpass

und so leute, denkt man.

Comment: Da dies ein Auftritt ist, der sich mit viel mit richtigem Sprachgebrauch befasst, wünschen wir uns sorgfältige Antworten, d.h. EInhaltung der Groß-/Kleinschreibung, Satzzeichen und ganze Sätze. Wenn Dein Gerät dafür nicht geeignet ist nutze bitte ein anderes, aber halse nicht den Anderen die Arbeit auf, Dein Posting in einen lesbaren Text zu verwandeln. Fehler kann jeder mal machen, aber hier wurde sich ja gar keine Mühe gegeben.