# beschränken vs. einschränken (Rechte, Freiheit, Pressefreiheit, Meinungsfreiheit usw.)

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen

- jemandes Rechte beschränken (jemanden in seinen Rechten/seiner Freiheit beschränken)
- jemandes Rechte einschränken

und sind die folgenden Ausdrücke Synonyme?

- eingeschränkte Pressefreiheit/Meinungsfreiheit/Freiheit
- beschränkte Pressefreiheit/Meinungsfreiheit/Freiheit

Comment: [Similar question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/beschränken-vs-einschränken-is-there-a-difference) in english.

Answer (score 8):

Im täglichen Sprachgebrauch werden die Begriffe meiner Meinung nach Synonym verwendet.

Im Synonymischen Handwörterbuch der deutschen Sprache von Johann August Eberhards aus dem Jahre 1910 steht aber:

> Beschränken bedeutet: hindern, daß ein Ding sich weiter ausdehne, und beschränkt ist also das, was gehindert wird, größer zu werden; einschränken hingegen heißt, ein Ding nötigen, sich einem gegebenen kleineren Raum gemäß zu verengern, und eingeschränkt ist also dasjenige, dem ein gewisser Raum bestimmt ist, in welchem es sich zusammenziehen muß. Das nämliche Ding ist daher beschränkt, sofern es seine Größe nicht über gewisse Schranken vermehren und ausdehnen kann; eingeschränkt, sofern es sich innerhalb der Schranken dieses Raumes halten muß. [...]

Siehe https://www.textlog.de/37975.html

Laut dieser Definition gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern *beschränken* und *einschränken*. Die Wörter *beschränkt* und *eingeschränkt* unterscheiden sich also dadurch, wie der Zustand der mangelnden Pressefreiheit erreicht wurde - ob die aktuelle Pressefreiheit aktiv aus einer "größeren" Pressefreiheit durch *Einschränkung* erreicht wurde oder passiv durch anfängliche *Beschränkung* nie ein gewisses Maß überschreiten konnte.

Ob diese Definition noch aktuell ist, kann ich nicht sagen. Sie ergibt für mich aber durchaus Sinn.

Comment: Exzellente Darstellung! Ich hatte etwas ähnliches gefühlt, doch war meine Belesenheit zu beschränkt, als dass ich dies hätte so formulieren können. Großes Lob ohne alle Einschränkung!

Comment: PS Im Sinne einer Kurzdefinition könnte man auch sagen: ***Beschränken*** ist ein Verhindern weiterer Ausdehnung. ***Einschränken*** ist ein Verringern bestehender Ausdehnung.

Comment: Ich würde noch hinzufügen: _beschränkt_ betont mehr den Zustand, _eingeschränkt_ betont eher, dass der Zustand Resultat eines Prozesses ist.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach   Es lebe die analytische Semantik!

Answer (score 1):

Die beiden Verben **einschränken** und **beschränken** sind fast bedeutungsgleich. Ein winziger Unterschied zeigt sich in der Nachfrage:

> Die Pressefreiheit wird eingeschränkt. — Klingt ja nicht so gut.
>
> Die Pressefreiheit wird beschränkt. — Auf was?

Ich lese daraus: Die Nutzung von *beschränken* setzt voraus, dass man diese Frage *auf was?* auch beantworten kann.

Comment: Ah, das ist eine interessante Nuance.

Comment: Vorschlag: Statt _auf was_ lieber _worauf_.